# Sort Array and delete the reamining objects from it

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array with multiple phrases, I want these phrases to appear randomly and do not show the other ones

Heres what i've got until now

```js
let phrases = ['some phrase', 'another phrase']

let shuffled = phrases
    .map((a) => ({sort: Math.random(), value: a}))
    .sort((a, b) => a.sort - b.sort)
    .map((a) => a.value)


const phraseHeading = document.querySelector('.phraseHeading')
phraseHeading.innerHTML = shuffled
```

```html
<h1 class="phraseHeading" ></h1>
```

I want the remaining phrases to disappear when the shuffle is ready

Comment: You want to display an item randomly?

Comment: You could jsut generate a random number with the range of the 0 and the length of the phrases array. And use that number as an index for the array to get a random phrase

Comment: You want only **one** phrase to appear? What do you mean with "other ones"? If you don't want to show more than one phrase, then sorting is overkill. Then just randomly pick one from the unsorted list.

Comment: I want to display random phrases and do not show the remaing ones, just one phrase appearing at a time, I want this to be modular, because I will put a lot of phrases inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply create a shuffle function using `Math.random` and using the array length as the upper limit of the random number:

```js
let phrases = ['some phrase', 'another phrase', 'another phrase']

const shuffle = arr => {
  randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(arr.length));
  return  arr[randomIndex];
}
let shuffled = shuffle(phrases);

const phraseHeading = document.querySelector('.phraseHeading')
phraseHeading.innerHTML = shuffled
```

```html
<h1 class="phraseHeading" ></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display random elements from an array with this:

```
alert(phrases[Math.floor(Math.random() * phrases.length)]);
```